# Too many HTTP redirects

Tags: objective-c, http

The problem doesn't happen all the time. The error i'm getting is the following,

```
Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1007 "too many HTTP redirects"
UserInfo=0x14d18d40{NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=URLHERE,
NSErrorFailingURLKey=URLHERE,NSLocalizedDescription=too many HTTP redirects,  
NSUnderlyingError=0x14d18a10 "too many HTTP redirects"}
```

Could someone possibly give me an idea on what do here and point me in the right direction?

Okay basically what i'm trying to do is when the doPortal is called, it loads up the Portal page with the URL. However when i do this, it shows the error about too many HTTP redirects.

Code:

```
 -(void)doPortal
{
    [ViewController SetRioSubjectName:[[ViewController getDictionaryOfKeys] objectForKey:[ViewController GetKeyName:k_SubjectName]] role:[ViewController getRoleID] ticket:[SpineMgr getTicket] TestURL:@"TestURL/login/testloginverifydetails.asp?database=LIVE&username=$spineuuid$&smartcardToken=$token$&role=$role$"];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:PortalURL];
    [self.webView loadRequest:request];
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post your code and please explain what you are trying to do

Comment: Are you certain that the error cannot be imparted on the URL: _TestURL/login/testloginverifydetails.asp?database=LIVE&username=$spineuuid$&smartcardToken=$token$&role=$role$_. Moreover, you're not replacing your `$`.

Answer (score -3):

```
NSString *html = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><body><a href=\"%@\">Link</body></html>", @"https://appian.com"];

[self.webView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];
```

Comment: please don't jsut post code bust also explain your solution