# How to handle "too many HTTP redirects" Error

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, redirect, nsurlrequest

This issue comes when i load website into  webview of my cocoa application.
my issue description:

> Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1007 "too many HTTP redirects"
>   UserInfo=0x18d17d56{NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=URLHERE,
>   NSErrorFailingURLKey=URLHERE,NSLocalizedDescription=too many HTTP
>   redirects}

why this error comes
how to handle it

i go though following links but does't help me

[Too many HTTP redirects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23221662/too-many-http-redirects)
["too many HTTP redirects" while using Alamofire Upload Multipart Form Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33727493/too-many-http-redirects-while-using-alamofire-upload-multipart-form-data)
[too many HTTP redirects, Google Drive, iOS SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38082914/too-many-http-redirects-google-drive-ios-sdk) and many more..

UPDATE:

```
- (NSURLRequest *)webView:(WebView *)sender resource:(id)identifier willSendRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request redirectResponse:(NSURLResponse *)redirectResponse fromDataSource:(WebDataSource *)dataSource {
    if(redirectResponse)
    {
        if([redirectResponse.URL.absoluteString isEqualToString:self.webviewLoadingURL.absoluteString])
        {
            NSLog(@"both redirect and load url is same");
        }
    }
    return request;
}
```

I getting same url for redirect and load in webview.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is almost invariably caused by a server configuration error that causes the web page to redirect to itself (possibly by way of another intermediate URL).  There's probably nothing you can do to fix this on the client side unless the problem is caused by your client code requesting an invalid/incorrect URL.

If you're asking how to present the error to the user, I would say that you should treat it in the same way that you'd treat a 404.  That URL isn't likely to start working any time soon.

Comment: In my case, the same error is occurring, but if I check the same URL in another browser app like Chrome in iOS than it is working fine.

Comment: That probably means that the redirection is cause by a missing cookie or by an unknown browser string.

Comment: In my case, I was missing the `www` at the beginning of the URL. So in the browser and POSTMAN it was always correct, but since the app cannot contact directly the server (because of the missing www) the response is a redirection... Crazy :

Comment: If this was a POST request, it's worth noting that the POST operation won't get replayed after a redirect, so your server should ideally be configured to handle POST requests directly rather than redirecting the user to the www site.  (I'm assuming that's what was happening.)

Answer (score 7):

I had this happen on an iPhone XS. It reported "too many HTTP redirects" only for a specific url no matter what I did. Even without an internet connection! Removing the app and reinstalling it solved the problem.

Comment: I was observed this issue on my cocoa (osx) application. But it is great to hear from you that reinstalling (iOS) application on iPhone may solve this problem. I have give your answer to +1 so may helps to other peoples

Comment: That likely means that there was a bad (redirecting) response in the cache.

Comment: Tom. Your answer has helped me too.